# Apple wireless keyboard visible in Bluetooth Devices but does not connect (feb 2017)

Tags: bluetooth

My Bluetooth device(apple keyboard) is visible in my list of Bluetooth Devices, but it doesn't connect!
When I try to manually pair it I get an error message saying

> 'Device added successfully, but failed to connect'

This has been asked several times before but there is a LOT of conflicting info on the correct solution for Ubuntu(in my case Ubuntu Mate 16.04).

Hence the reason for re-asking
I am using an Asus BT400 Bluetooth dongle

Answer (score 1):

Try using terminal, put the keyboard in pairing mode then in terminal

```
bluetoothctl
```

It should show the controller- your Bluetooth dongle's MAC address

Then in terminal

```
power on
scan on
```

Now it should discover your keyboard and show it's MAC address

```
pair keyboards MAC
```

Replace keyboards MAC with just the MAC and the MAC address is case sensitive and letters need to be caps.  You may be asked to type a PIN code on the keyboard and press enter. Then try

```
trust keyboards MAC
connect keyboards MAC
```

You shouldn't have to type the entire MAC address, just type the first digits and press TAB key to autocomplete